# Recyclerview is not showing data from Firebase Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, kotlin

As title says, I'm using since yesterday **Kotlin**. I want to populate a **RecyclerView** with data from **Firebase**.

I tried something, I built an Adapter and tried to populate the **RecyclerView**, my data is going to Firebasebase but not showing in the **RecyclerView** and I get no errors.

I couldn't find any tutorials for my problem with **Kotlin** language

**Here is my Adapter:**

```
class QuestionAdapter(var items : ArrayList<Question>): RecyclerView.Adapter<QuestionAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return items.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
    var userDto = items[position]
    holder?.titleTextView?.text = userDto.titlu
    holder?.msgTextView?.text = userDto.uid
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.conv_layout, parent, false)

    return ViewHolder(itemView)
}

class ViewHolder(row: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(row) {
    var titleTextView: TextView? = null
    var msgTextView: TextView? = null

    init {
        this.titleTextView = row?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.titleTextView)
        this.msgTextView = row?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.msgTextView)
    }
}
}
```

And here is my code for Activity:

```
 private fun populalteQuestionsList() {
    val mChatDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child(Constants.USERS).child(mUserID).child(Constants.CHAT).child(Constants.QUESTION)
    val query = mChatDatabaseReference.orderByChild("time")
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
            mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
            val  questions = ArrayList<Question>()
            val adapter = QuestionAdapter(questions)
            mRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
        }
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError?) {
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Recyclerview is not showing data from Firebase Kotlin

Because you are not adding any data inside your **`questions`** `ArrayList<Question>()`

check in your  code

Try this

```
override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
            mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
            val  questions = ArrayList<Question>()
            val adapter = QuestionAdapter(questions)
           // add data here inside your questions ArrayList<Question>()
            mRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

i hope in your adater define getItemCount() method then you can change below code ...

```
private fun populalteQuestionsList() {
    val mChatDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child(Constants.USERS).child(mUserID).child(Constants.CHAT).child(Constants.QUESTION)
    val query = mChatDatabaseReference.orderByChild("time")
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
            mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
            val  questions = ArrayList<Question>()
            val question = dataSnapshot.getValue(Question::class.java)
            questions.add(question)
            val adapter = QuestionAdapter(questions)
            mRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()        
        }
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError?) {
        }
    })
}
```

and i hope in adapter have below method ...

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}
```

Comment: when you copy getItemCount() method into adapter it automatic convert into kotlin. and also check your firebase database store question class data and check onDataChange method give data or not.

Comment: I know but this line, I can't convert and it's not working "questions.addAll(dataSnapshot.getValue(Question.class));"

Comment: sorry for that you can add this line    val question = dataSnapshot.getValue(Question::class.java)
                questions.add(question)

Comment: sorry that i'm bothering you, val question = dataSnapshot.getValue(Question::class.java)  is instead of  val  questions = ArrayList<Question>() ?

Comment: i don't know still nothing. would mind if i would start a discussion chat with you ?

Comment: you can check onDataChange Method call or not.then check you firebase data base node is given question data or not.